# Elements not showing in UIWebView (Hybrid App)

Tags: ios, css, uiwebview

I have a hybrid app [Xpresso](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xpresso-funny-gif-maker/id1166463415?mt=8). My app works fine in Android WebView but in iOS the problem which is happening is that its not displaying the elements in the page and shows blank sometimes.

That problem happens either while coming from a different page or using scroll up and down (or right and left) many times.

Given below are two examples where in the first image all elements are not shown except the color tab and in the second image all elements are visible except the color tab.

PS : All elements are working properly, just that its not showing. If you tap on the respective places, the respective actions will be performed.

PPS : I am using AngularJS, HTML5 & CSS3.

[image]
[image]

Comment: could you please tell the platform you are using or any plugin being used?

Comment: Maybe problem in route? You use iOnic?

Comment: No, not iONIC, Why?
It starts showing when touched in the screen a lot times or come to that page again from another page.

Comment: @AliFarhan I am using AngularJS, HTML5 and CSS